# Surprising behaviour using TemplateEngine with variable "URL" interpreted as class

Tags: templates, groovy

Given the following Groovy code:

```
def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
def propMap = [ URL: "http://stackoverflow.com",URL2: "http://stackoverflow.com"]
def result = engine.createTemplate('''

${URL}
${URL2}

''').make(propMap) as String
println(java.net.URL)
```

the output is

```
class java.net.URL
http://stackoverflow.com
```

Somehow the `URL` ends up being interpreted as class `java.net.URL` (which Groovy seems to be auto-importing), but why? And can a variable named `URL` used in this context?

Comment: Don't have variables called URL, String, File, etc. Lowercase is fine, but shadowing actual class names is always going to give you problems

Comment: @tim_yates: sure, it is possible to avoid that names but why would Groovy interpret it in such a way? In Java, it is possible to use that name, even if it does not adhere to coding standards... of course, Groovy is a dynamic language, but still it seems surprising

Comment: Because it imports that class by default

Answer (score 2):

Groovy is making several [default imports](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_default_imports), which also includes `java.net`. Import `java.net.URL` apparently shadows your local variable.

You could use `this` to explicitly tell Groovy to use your variable instead of `java.net.URL`.

```
${this.URL}
${URL2}
```

I also tried to use alias for import like this:

`import java.net.URL as JavaURL`

but it didn't really help, because both implicit (`URL`) and explicit (`JavaURL`) imports were used.